# How do I move every 7 columns to the next empty row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data from A1 to BOO66262 and I need to fit everything in seven columns, regardless of the number of rows. I currently have:

```
     | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | ... | BOO
1    | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | ... | x
...  | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | ... | .
66262| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | ... | x
```

I need the worksheet to only have seven columns like so:

```
    | A | B | C | D | E | F | G
1   | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
... | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
n   | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
```

Every group has 7 columns but vary in the number of rows. Does anyone know how to do this with VBA?

Here's a screenshot of how my spreadsheet currently looks:[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is the total number of rows in the aggregated 7 columns going to exceed 1048576?

Comment: There are about 5.02 million non-empty cells so there will approximately be a little over 700 thousand rows. @Jeeped

EDIT: I miscounted. There are only 2.2 million cells which will result in 300,000 rows.

Comment: Generally speaking, a show of original effort toward a solution is expected in the Excel forum. Judging from your last (excellent) question on r, quantmodr and mysql I believe you understand the [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) process.

Answer (score 0):

Open the VBE with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and put the following into a module code sheet.

```
Sub play_tetris()
    Dim rws As Long, cls As Long, i As Long
    Dim v As Long, vs As Long, vTMP As Variant, vVALs As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            ReDim vVALs(1 To Application.CountA(.Cells) / 7, 1 To 7)
        End With
        For cls = 1 To Range("BOO1").Column Step 7
            rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, cls).End(xlUp).Row
            vTMP = .Cells(1, cls).Resize(rws, 7).Value2
            For v = LBound(vTMP, 1) To UBound(vTMP, 1)
                vs = vs + 1
                For i = 1 To 7
                    vVALs(vs, i) = vTMP(v, i)
                Next i
            Next v
        Next cls
        With .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), 7)
            .Value = vVALs
            .Rows(1).Copy
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            .Resize(1, Range("BOO1").Column).Offset(0, 7).EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Adjust the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) in the fourth line if you are not working on Sheet1. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the worksheet then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the **Macro** dialog and Run the macro.